# SqlCommandBuilder and SQL Server Computed Columns - Error

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, sqldataadapter, sqlcommandbuilder

What is the right way to avoid errors on INSERT and UPDATES with a SqlDataAdapter/SqlCommandbuilder when the SQL Statement used to SELECT has a computed column as one of the return fields?

I get the error now that "The column *Amount* cannot be modified because it is either a computed column or is the result of a UNION operator".

**UPDATE**: 
I fixed the issue by using a query like this:

```
SELECT *, PercentRating * 500 AS CoreValue FROM ValueListings
```

And ditching the computed column.
Now it works. How is that SqlCommandBuilder realizes to *NOT* build the CoreValue field into the UPDATE and INSERT statements? Anybody know how this works internally?

Comment: Good news with your fix, shame your using the dreaded select star notiation!

Comment: What's wrong with the select * notation? I'm trying to keep the SQL simple because these statements are embedded in a DSL.

Comment: The problem with using select * is that it might affect performance, depending in the number of records and columns that this table has. For example, if you only need 3 columns out of a table with 8 columns it is better to call select column1, column2, column3 instead of select * as it will return a lot of data that you don't need.

Comment: But I need all the columns! so I'm still baffled by Chalkey's remark.

Answer (score 1):

Use The Sentence:

SELECT * FROM ValueListings

Then After Fill the DataTable, add a Computed Column to it:

```
  Dim Dt as new DataTable
  Da.Fill(Dt)
  Dt.columns.add("CoreValue", GetType(Double), "PercentRating * 500")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can avoid using the * it WILL save you trouble later.  With * if you change the schema your code may break.  If named fields, you're good.